# Is it possible to add terms to the dictionaries of `lexicon` package?

Tags: r, dictionary, lexicon, sentimentr

The package `sentimentr` provides tools to calculate text polarity sentiment at the sentence level and
optionally aggregate by rows or grouping variable. One of its functions, `sentiment`, approximates the sentiment (polarity) of text by sentence. In particular,

```
sentiment(text.var, polarity_dt = lexicon::hash_sentiment_jockers_rinker, ...)
```

`text.var` is the text variable, whereas `polarity_dt` is the dictionary provided by `lexicon` package. I would like to know whether it is possible to extend the set of terms in the `lexicon` dictionaries, by adding words (with their corresponding scores) to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. The sentiment tables are just data.tables. If you have words to add just create your own table and add these to the lexicon. See example below.

```
library(sentimentr)
library(data.table)

extra_terms <- data.table(x = c("word1", "word2"),
                          y = c(1.0, -1.0), 
                          key = "x")
# merge data with lexicon
my_lex <- merge(lexicon::hash_sentiment_jockers_rinker, extra_terms, by = c("x", "y"), all = TRUE)

sentiment(text.var, polarity_dt = my_lex, ...)
```